# AngularJS ng-repeat item to function as argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to send an item value from ng-repeat to a function as argument..But i cant do it..

I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies" class="col-sm-4 animated bounceInLeft">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                <span class="panel-title text" ng-bind="company.company"/>
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-left:1em;">
                <img src="images/build/loading.gif" ng-show="waitingResponse"></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-cool input pull-right" placeholder="Nueva categoria"
                       ng-model="worktype" name="worktype" id="worktype"/> <strong>
                        <span>
                            <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Añadir tipo de trabajo"
                                    ng-click="addWorktype(company._id)"
                                    class="btn btn-header btn-link animated pulse-btn"
                                    style="color:#ffffff; font-size:20px;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span></strong>
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-left:1em;">
                    </span>
                <img src="images/build/loading.gif" ng-show="updatingWarehouses"></span>
            </div>
```

But if i put the company._id inside the ng-click the input dont appears in HTML...Is there any way to do it this..?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to show what it does and what you are expecting it to do? It's hard to say from this messy piece of code

Comment: Sorry is complicated do a fiddle for me with this.. I hope when i click in the button, this call a controller function with the company element as argument, but when i put ng-click="addWorktype(company._id)" the input dont show in the page..

Comment: this doesn't work either? `ng-click="addWorktype(company)"`

Comment: where is addWorktype ?

Comment: Now works..thnaks @doodeec